Test Cases on Redux Toolkit Query not giving expected result
I am writing test cases for redux toolkit query but it is not giving me expected results.
This is my api.ts
export const notificationApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'notificationApi',
  baseQuery:  fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: config.BASE_API_URL }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getNotifications: builder.query({
      query: ({ name, page, limit }) => ({
        url: `/api/getNotificationList/${name}/${page + 1}/${limit}`,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetNotificationsQuery } = notificationApi;

And This is the test case that I have written
import { waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { renderHookWithProviders } from 'common/tests/renderWithProviders';
import { http, HttpResponse } from 'msw';
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node';

import { useGetNotificationsQuery } from './api';

const server = setupServer(
  http.get('/api/getNotificationList/Data/2/10', () => {
    return HttpResponse.json({
      data: 'mockedData',
    });
  }),
);

beforeAll(() => server.listen());
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
afterAll(() => server.close());

test('useGetNotificationsQuery performs the API call and returns the data', async () => {
  const { result } = renderHookWithProviders(() =>
    useGetNotificationsQuery({ name: 'Data', page: 1, limit: 10 }),
  );

  expect(result.current).toMatchObject({
    status: 'pending',
    endpointName: 'getNotificationList',
    isLoading: true,
    isSuccess: false,
    isError: false,
    isFetching: true,
  });

  await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.isSuccess).toBe(true));
  console.log('result-->', result);
});

result.current.isSuccess is not coming out to be true. It is always false. Hence I am not able to proceed further. Can anyone help here ?
To add to this -
I am getting this error -
error: {
      name: 'TypeError',
      message: 'Failed to parse URL from /api/getNotificationsList/Data/2/10',
      stack: 'TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /api/getNotificationsList/Data/2/10\n' +
        '    at new Request (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5272:19)\n' +
        '    at file:///D:/Repository/Repo/Frontend/admin/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/src/query/fetchBaseQuery.ts:224:21\n' +
        '    at baseQuery (D:\\Repository\\Frontend\\admin\\src\\redux\\api\\api.ts:12:20)\n' +     
        '    at executeEndpoint (file:///D:/Repository/Frontend/admin/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/src/query/core/buildThunks.ts:217:18)\n' +
        '    at file:///D:/Repository/Frontend/admin/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/src/createAsyncThunk.ts:336:27\n' +
        '    at async Promise.all (index 1)'
    },


Does it matter that your endpoint is hitting "/api/getNotificationList/:name/:page/:limit" but your test is mocking "/api/admin/getNotificationList/Data/2/10"? There's an extra path segment in the MSW mock.

I have edited the code, that was by mistake.

requests in node need a hostname. "http://example.com/api/admin/getNotificationList/Data/2/10" would be okay.
